# SSJS is not printing variable value in cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying to print the value of a SSJS variable in cloud page so that i can use it in my HTML to display over cloud page . but page keeps loading without any output.

```
<body>
 <script runat="server">
      Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
var array = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    write( i + "<br>");
}
</script>
  <a> Click here </a>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay . i got my mistake . I was not using Stringfy function to print the output of variable.

Comment: That is actually not true. The issue is that you used write instead of Write. It is case sensitive. You do not need Stringify to print out a string. Write( i + "<br>"); works fine.

Comment: Yeah you are correct . My mistake was that too but i changed both thing in my code . So i missed that to point out. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my mistake . I was using write instead of Write as pointed out by - shd.lux